# Added GIT to CodeIgniter - now have file errors

Tags: php, git, codeigniter

New to GIT, new to CodeIgniter (perfect storm).

I've initialised a git repository in my existing CI project. Then opened the application in Eclipse and there are a few folders with red x's or yellow exclamation marks (see pic).

[image: Errors on folders caused by GIT install]

Can anyone point out what I need to change here?

As requested, here is the content of respond.js (it's minified I'm afraid so just one big line).

Also, here are the errors shown in the console when I run the application:

The key "width-device-width" is not recognized and ignored. home:4
The key "initial-scale-1.0" is not recognized and ignored. home:4
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

```
!function(a){"use strict";a.matchMedia=a.matchMedia||function(a){var b,c=a.documentElement,d=c.firstElementChild||c.firstChild,e=a.createElement("body"),f=a.createElement("div");return f.id="mq-test-1",f.style.cssText="position:absolute;top:-100em",e.style.background="none",e.appendChild(f),function(a){return f.innerHTML='&shy;<style media="'+a+'"> #mq-test-1 { width: 42px; }</style>',c.insertBefore(e,d),b=42===f.offsetWidth,c.removeChild(e),{matches:b,media:a}}}(a.document)}(this),function(a){"use strict";function b(){v(!0)}var c={};a.respond=c,c.update=function(){};var d=[],e=function(){var b=!1;try{b=new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(c){b=new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}return function(){return b}}(),f=function(a,b){var c=e();c&&(c.open("GET",a,!0),c.onreadystatechange=function(){4!==c.readyState||200!==c.status&&304!==c.status||b(c.responseText)},4!==c.readyState&&c.send(null))},g=function(a){return a.replace(c.regex.minmaxwh,"").match(c.regex.other)};if(c.ajax=f,c.queue=d,c.unsupportedmq=g,c.regex={media:/@media[^\{]+\{([^\{\}]*\{[^\}\{]*\})+/gi,keyframes:/@(?:\-(?:o|moz|webkit)\-)?keyframes[^\{]+\{(?:[^\{\}]*\{[^\}\{]*\})+[^\}]*\}/gi,comments:/\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*\//gi,urls:/(url\()['"]?([^\/\)'"][^:\)'"]+)['"]?(\))/g,findStyles:/@media *([^\{]+)\{([\S\s]+?)$/,only:/(only\s+)?([a-zA-Z]+)\s?/,minw:/\(\s*min\-width\s*:\s*(\s*[0-9\.]+)(px|em)\s*\)/,maxw:/\(\s*max\-width\s*:\s*(\s*[0-9\.]+)(px|em)\s*\)/,minmaxwh:/\(\s*m(in|ax)\-(height|width)\s*:\s*(\s*[0-9\.]+)(px|em)\s*\)/gi,other:/\([^\)]*\)/g},c.mediaQueriesSupported=a.matchMedia&&null!==a.matchMedia("only all")&&a.matchMedia("only all").matches,!c.mediaQueriesSupported){var h,i,j,k=a.document,l=k.documentElement,m=[],n=[],o=[],p={},q=30,r=k.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||l,s=k.getElementsByTagName("base")[0],t=r.getElementsByTagName("link"),u=function(){var a,b=k.createElement("div"),c=k.body,d=l.style.fontSize,e=c&&c.style.fontSize,f=!1;return b.style.cssText="position:absolute;font-size:1em;width:1em",c||(c=f=k.createElement("body"),c.style.background="none"),l.style.fontSize="100%",c.style.fontSize="100%",c.appendChild(b),f&&l.insertBefore(c,l.firstChild),a=b.offsetWidth,f?l.removeChild(c):c.removeChild(b),l.style.fontSize=d,e&&(c.style.fontSize=e),a=j=parseFloat(a)},v=function(b){var c="clientWidth",d=l[c],e="CSS1Compat"===k.compatMode&&d||k.body[c]||d,f={},g=t[t.length-1],p=(new Date).getTime();if(b&&h&&q>p-h)return a.clearTimeout(i),i=a.setTimeout(v,q),void 0;h=p;for(var s in m)if(m.hasOwnProperty(s)){var w=m[s],x=w.minw,y=w.maxw,z=null===x,A=null===y,B="em";x&&(x=parseFloat(x)*(x.indexOf(B)>-1?j||u():1)),y&&(y=parseFloat(y)*(y.indexOf(B)>-1?j||u():1)),w.hasquery&&(z&&A||!(z||e>=x)||!(A||y>=e))||(f[w.media]||(f[w.media]=[]),f[w.media].push(n[w.rules]))}for(var C in o)o.hasOwnProperty(C)&&o[C]&&o[C].parentNode===r&&r.removeChild(o[C]);o.length=0;for(var D in f)if(f.hasOwnProperty(D)){var E=k.createElement("style"),F=f[D].join("\n");E.type="text/css",E.media=D,r.insertBefore(E,g.nextSibling),E.styleSheet?E.styleSheet.cssText=F:E.appendChild(k.createTextNode(F)),o.push(E)}},w=function(a,b,d){var e=a.replace(c.regex.comments,"").replace(c.regex.keyframes,"").match(c.regex.media),f=e&&e.length||0;b=b.substring(0,b.lastIndexOf("/"));var h=function(a){return a.replace(c.regex.urls,"$1"+b+"$2$3")},i=!f&&d;b.length&&(b+="/"),i&&(f=1);for(var j=0;f>j;j++){var k,l,o,p;i?(k=d,n.push(h(a))):(k=e[j].match(c.regex.findStyles)&&RegExp.$1,n.push(RegExp.$2&&h(RegExp.$2))),o=k.split(","),p=o.length;for(var q=0;p>q;q++)l=o[q],g(l)||m.push({media:l.split("(")[0].match(c.regex.only)&&RegExp.$2||"all",rules:n.length-1,hasquery:l.indexOf("(")>-1,minw:l.match(c.regex.minw)&&parseFloat(RegExp.$1)+(RegExp.$2||""),maxw:l.match(c.regex.maxw)&&parseFloat(RegExp.$1)+(RegExp.$2||"")})}v()},x=function(){if(d.length){var b=d.shift();f(b.href,function(c){w(c,b.href,b.media),p[b.href]=!0,a.setTimeout(function(){x()},0)})}},y=function(){for(var b=0;b<t.length;b++){var c=t[b],e=c.href,f=c.media,g=c.rel&&"stylesheet"===c.rel.toLowerCase();e&&g&&!p[e]&&(c.styleSheet&&c.styleSheet.rawCssText?(w(c.styleSheet.rawCssText,e,f),p[e]=!0):(!/^([a-zA-Z:]*\/\/)/.test(e)&&!s||e.replace(RegExp.$1,"").split("/")[0]===a.location.host)&&("//"===e.substring(0,2)&&(e=a.location.protocol+e),d.push({href:e,media:f})))}x()};y(),c.update=y,c.getEmValue=u,a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener("resize",b,!1):a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("onresize",b)}}(this);
```

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: can you post the content of `respond.js`? thats where the error seems to exist.

Comment: This is a very low chance that this is due to git as git doesn't directly change your code at all (unless you rebase, revert commit, etc). This is certainly due to the fact that Perfect Storm didn't crawl the inners of all your files, but did it when you initialized git.

Comment: @Subash I've added the respond.js. This was a copy and paste when I was following a bootstrap tutorial on lynda.com.

Comment: @BabyAzerty I did think it wasn't logical that GIT would have changed anything to cause errors. FYI when I talk about 'Perfect Storm' - I mean the fact that I'm new to GIT and CI. My IDE is Eclipse with PHP Tools installed. Thanks, Gareth

Comment: @gazrolo4 do you get any errors when you run the application? in the console?

Comment: @Subash Thanks Subash. I've edited with the errors that are present in the console. I guess this must have always been the case, but git init has obviously done something that has made Eclipse recognise the errors?

Comment: There are errors being highlighted in Eclipse (warnings) in the Bootstrap files too - these were just a straight copy from the bootstrap site. Stuff like missing semicolons etc. Only a few instances. Just don't get why it's become an issue once GIT has been installed?? The application itself is running fine though (albeit with a few console errors).

Comment: @gazrolo4 You should totally ask the Bootstrap guys to add semi-colons to their code. I'm sure they'll be accommodating

Comment: @Phil Do I detect some sarcasm there by any chance? Like I said, it's not really the errors I'm concerned about, it's just why they have only started to be flagged in Eclipse now and (essentially) whether I safely ignore these issues

Comment: @gazrolo4 there should be no connection of git and the error in your javascript. Just by reading the question and the javascript file, I am unable to help you as its not enough information to work with. If you send me your project files, I might be able to debug the actual issue.